# VB.NET RemoveHandler & Anonymous Methods

Tags: vb.net, anonymous-methods, addhandler

How do I use `RemoveHandler` with anonymous methods?

This is how I add a handler for `MyEvent` event of the class `MyClass`:

```
AddHandler MyClass.MyEvent, Sub()
                                '...
                            End Sub
```

How do I then use `RemoveHandler` to remove the handler for the `MyEvent` event?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

In general, if you need to unsubscribe from the event, I would recommend not using a lambda like this, and instead use a standard method.

That being said, you can still use the anonymous method, but you need to store a reference to it for the unsubscription.  If you must unsubscribe an anonymous method, at a minimum, you should store the delegate in a variable to remove it later:

```
Dim subscription = Sub()
                            ' ...
                   End Sub

AddHandler MyClass.MyEvent, subscription

' Later   
RemoveHandler MyClass.MyEvent, subscription
```

Comment: Makes senses.  If that's the case there's no point using anonymous methods when I have to remove it at a later time.

Comment: @acermate433s: True, which is why I suggested using a standard method. The one advantage of a lambda, thoguh, is you can close over local variables instead of promoting them to class level, which can be useful at times...