# How to remove an event handler in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, winforms, handler

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [VB.NET RemoveHandler & Anonymous Methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7447168/vb-net-removehandler-anonymous-methods)

If I add an event handler like this:

```
AddHandler s.Click, AddressOf Panel1_Click
```

How can I can then remove the event handler?

```
Private Sub Panel1_click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    ' Remove code
End Sub
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can do so using the `RemoveHandler` operator, as such:

```
Private Sub Panel1_click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    Dim panel As Panel = CType(sender, Panel)
    RemoveHandler panel.Click, AddressOf Panel1_Click
End Sub
```

Answer (score 9):

The same way you added it:

```
RemoveHandler s.Click, AddressOf Panel1_Click
```

[Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/removehandler-statement)

Comment: Surely the *opposite* way to the way you added it :) +1 anyway