# Change button event handler at runtime

Tags: vb.net, dynamic, event-handling, runtime

How do you change an event handler at runtime? In my case I have a AddIn for AutodeskInventor.

Based on what the user selects I want a button to do different things. So I should remove the current active handler and add a new one.

But I don't want to "save" what handler was added when the user made another selection.

So how do you change the event handler if you don't know what handler is currently active?

[MSDN Help page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6yyk8z93%28v=vs.90%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

```
RemoveHandler c1.AnEvent, AddressOf EventHandler2
AddHandler c1.AnEvent, AddressOf EventHandler2
```

Comment: Can you explain why you don't want to 'save' the current event handler?

Comment: It seems easier if you could `get` the current handler(s) instead of saving them?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7447168/vb-net-removehandler-anonymous-methods